# How to Set Variables in a Laravel Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm reading the Laravel Blade [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) and I can't figure out how to assign variables inside a template for use later. I can't do `{{ $old_section = "whatever" }}` because that will echo "whatever" and I don't want that.

I understand that I can do `<?php $old_section = "whatever"; ?>`, but that's not elegant.

Is there a better, elegant way to do that in a Blade template?

Comment: Check this pull : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/866

Comment: This is often useful for testing, especially if you are working on the template but someone else works on the PHP part. Just be careful to remove the declaration when you are done testing.

Comment: What's  is wrong with simply doing `<?php $old_section = "whatever"; ?>`. I find it quite readable.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel the answer, in my opinion, is in the question: it's not elegant.

Comment: @duality_ Using a hack is always going to be inelegant, don't look for elegance if you want to use hacks.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It is discouraged to do in a view so there is no blade tag for it.
If you do want to do this in your blade view, you can either just open a php tag as you wrote it or register a new blade tag. Just an example:

```php
<?php
/**
 * <code>
 * {? $old_section = "whatever" ?}
 * </code>
 */
Blade::extend(function($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\{\?(.+)\?\}/', '<?php ${1} ?>', $value);
});
```

Comment: Variables in views have some uses. This looks great! Where would be a good place to put this code?

Comment: You can put it in your application/start.php or if you will have more things like this put it in a separate file and include it there. Laravel is very loose in this way, you could even put thin a controller. The only thing you have to do these extends before the view is rendered.

Comment: For LARAVEL 4 add this code to the end of the global.php file in the app/start

Comment: What is the reasoning for adding this extra code just to use `{?` instead of just using the native `<?` ?

Comment: If it is discouraged to do, is there a more "proper" way to do the following? I have a site where the title is rendered in the main app view as {{ $title }}, which contains a subsystem who needs to append the page number to the title ("Application Form Page {{ $page }}") and I am passing $page to the view (which is used otherwise within the view).  I don't want to build the title in each controller call, I just want to send the view the page number - just in case some day I want to change the base title. I'm using <?php $title = ... ?> now, but is there a more correct way?

Comment: Variables should be passed from the controller, not declared inline in your view. If a global template needs a variable, you can set it in a service provider http://stackoverflow.com/a/36780419/922522. If a page specific template needs a variable, use @yield and pass it from the child view that has a controller. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Laravel's manual points out that you can use PHP in blade templates as one of blade's strenghts. "Unlike other popular PHP templating engines, Blade does not restrict you from using plain PHP code in your views." - second sentence in the docs. I go for PHP tags. Pretty enough and absolutely easy to understand for everyone.

Comment: Use `@php` and `@endphp` tags built into blade.  Using this answer does not leave the variable set in the blade template in laravel 5.3+

Answer (score 494):

**EASY WAY**

If you want to define multiple variables, use the full form of the blade directive:

```
@php
   $i = 1;
   $j = 2;
@endphp
```

If you only want to define one variable, you can also use a single PHP statement:

```
@php($i = 1)
```

**MORE ADVANCED: ADD A 'DEFINE' TAG**

If you want to use custom tags and use a @define instead of @php, extend Blade like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Extend blade so we can define a variable
| <code>
| @define $variable = "whatever"
| </code>
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

\Blade::extend(function($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\@define(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
});
```

Then do one of the following:

**Quick solution**: If you are lazy, just put the code in the boot() function of the AppServiceProvider.php.

**Nicer solution**:
Create an own service provider. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28641054/2169147 on how to extend blade in Laravel 5. It's a bit more work this way, but a good exercise on how to use Providers :)

After the above changes, you can use:

```
@define $i = 1
```

to define a variable.

Comment: Nice! Please note that you can execute any php statement with your implementation. I would rename it to soemething like @php. Very handy...

Comment: Very true, igaster. You can rename 'define' to 'php' if you want, but that opens the pitfall to over-using php in your templates :)

Comment: I'm currently running the LTS (5.1) version. I had to add `\ ` before Blade::extend... That is explained in the given link tho. But I thought it's worth to mention. Absolute elegant solution btw. `+1` !

Comment: Thanks @C.delaFonteijne, if you are using namespacing (and you should), the \ is indeed needed. I've added the \ in the code above.

Comment: Please note that almost your exact implementation is standard [since Laravel 5.2](https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/5.2/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L797-L819). You can use `@php(@i = 1)` or use it in a block statement (close with `@endphp`)

Comment: Awsome
{{-- */$i=0;/* --}} use to work with laravel 5.2 does not in 5.3
@php ($i = 1) works perfectly in 5.3

Comment: I don't see how "@php" "@endphp" is "more elegant" than "<?php" "?>". It's even a few characters longer! Is it just because it starts with a "@" like other Blade directives? We developers are some obsessive-compulsive bunch! ;-)

Comment: What is meant with your first sentence: The @php blade directive no longer accepts inline tags. Instead, use the full form of the directive ...

Does that meant that `@php ($i = 1)` isn't valid anymore or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @ralphjsmit indeed `@php ($i = 1)` should not be working anymore, although I have not tested this in the newest versions. You should now use:

`@php 
$i = 1 
@endphp`

Comment: @Pim Ok thanks for confirming! I just tried it and the old syntax does still work (Laravel 8.33.1). Anyway, it's more future proof to use the new one.

Answer (score 119):

In [laravel-4](/questions/tagged/laravel-4), you can use the template comment syntax to define/set variables.

Comment syntax is  `{{-- anything here is comment --}}` and it is rendered by [blade](/questions/tagged/blade) engine as

`<?php /* anything here is comment */ ?>`

so with little trick we can use it to define variables, for example

```
{{-- */$i=0;/* --}}
```

will be rendered by [blade](/questions/tagged/blade)as 
    `<?php /* */$i=0;/* */ ?>` which sets the variable for us. 
Without changing any line of code.

Comment: @trying-tobemyself +1 | Not the *Best-Practices* way, but _perfect_ for quick hacking of code in templates like with _inline styles_ for html.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this hack as anyone who looks at this code after you is going to hate you.

Comment: Agree with Justin, comment tags are for comments, to uncomment within the comment and start doing something else is asking for trouble

Comment: I find this useful for debugging when stepping through a template in PHPStorm

Comment: This is not better than plain ol' php `<?php $i=0; ?>`

Comment: This could win a code obfuscation contest over on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the point of doing this instead of using php tags?? It's not readable (looks like a comment), requires more typing, and may get broken with an update to the parsing system. Even if it has a point, it's not the answer to how to define a variable in a blade template. Don't know what's wrong with the voters, perhaps they found this so 'geeky'? meh...

Comment: this like hack life :)

Answer (score 62):

There is a simple workaround that doesn't require you to change any code, and it works in Laravel 4 just as well.

You just use an assignment operator (`=`) in the expression passed to an `@if` statement, instead of (for instance) an operator such as `==`.

```
@if ($variable = 'any data, be it string, variable or OOP') @endif
```

Then you can use it anywhere you can use any other variable

```
{{ $variable }}
```

The only downside is your assignment will *look* like a mistake to someone not aware that you're doing this as a workaround.

Answer (score 39):

Ya'll are making it too complicated.

Just use plain php

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
{{$i}}
```

donesies.

(or https://github.com/alexdover/blade-set looks pretty straighforward too)

We're all kinda "hacking" the system by setting variables in views, so why make the "hack" more complicated then it needs to be?

Tested in Laravel 4.

Another benefit is that syntax highlighting works properly (I was using comment hack before and it was awful to read)

Answer (score 28):

Since Laravel 5.2.23, you have the [@php Blade directive](http://themsaid.com/laravel-5-2-23-20160305/), which you can use inline or as block statement:

```
@php($old_section = "whatever")
```

or

```
@php
    $old_section = "whatever"
@endphp
```

Answer (score 23):

You Can Set Variables In The Blade Templating Engine The Following Ways:
**1. General PHP Block**
**Setting Variable:** `<?php $hello = "Hello World!"; ?>`
**Output:** `{{$hello}}`
**2. Blade PHP Block**
**Setting Variable:** `@php $hello = "Hello World!"; @endphp`
**Output:** `{{$hello}}`

Answer (score 20):

You can set a variable in the view file, but it will be printed just as you set it. Anyway, there is a workaround. You can set the variable inside an unused section. Example:

```
@section('someSection')
  {{ $yourVar = 'Your value' }}
@endsection
```

Then `{{ $yourVar }}` will print `Your value` anywhere you want it to, but you don't get the output when you save the variable.

**EDIT:** naming the section is required otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Doesn't work something else need to be included Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$startSection (View: /home/vagrant/Code/dompetspy/resources/views/reviews/index.blade.php)

Comment: Actually that's very smart! Just call your section 'variables' and use it strictly for assigning variables in blade and voila!

Answer (score 19):

In laravel document https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#php
You can do this way:

```
@php
     $my_variable = 123;
@endphp
```

Comment: Why do adding already existing answers?

Answer (score 17):

**In Laravel 4:**

If you wanted the variable accessible in all your views, not just your template, `View::share` is a great method ([more info on this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315064629/http://atomicplayboy.net/blog/2013/06/25/global-view-variables-in-laravel/)).

Just add the following in *app/controllers/BaseController.php*

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {                   
    // Share a var with all views
    View::share('myvar', 'some value');
  }
}
```

and now `$myvar` will be available to all your views -- including your template.

I used this to set environment specific asset URLs for my images.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: great way to avoid duplicate calls at database!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an option in Laravel 5?

Comment: @Goddard You still can. Syntax has changed though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36780419/922522

Answer (score 9):

**Laravel 7 :**

```
{{ $solution = "Laravel 7 is awesome and easy to use !!" }}
```

Comment: When i define the variable like this the website print out the value of $solution, how can i fix this. So that the variable is just defined in the blade.php but is not printed out ?

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using. @MariusIllmann

Answer (score 8):

And suddenly nothing will appear.
From my experience, if you have to do something like this prepare the html in a model's method or do some reorganizing of your code in to arrays or something.

There is never just 1 way.

```
{{ $x = 1 ? '' : '' }}
```

Comment: Prepare the HTML in the model? That's the ugliest thing imaginable.

Comment: @duality_ You're declaring and changing variables in your view.  I said you're probably organizing your code wrong. Lrn 2 architect.

Comment: Sure thing, Michael... Those variables are not variables such as `$users = ...`, but something along the lines `$css_class = ...`, so strictly design variables that don't belong to the model or controller, as they are determined by the designer.

Comment: if you need to go that route, I prefer the more simple and elegant solution: {{ ''; $x = 1 }}

Answer (score 7):

**In Laravel 5.1, 5.2**:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

> You may need to share a piece of data with **all views** that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view factory's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them.

Edit file: `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{        
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('key', 'value');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to extend the answer given by @Pim.

Add this to the boot method of your AppServiceProvider

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Extend blade so we can define a variable
| <code>
| @set(name, value)
| </code>
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Blade::directive('set', function($expression) {
    list($name, $val) = explode(',', $expression);
    return "<?php {$name} = {$val}; ?>";
});
```

This way you don't expose the ability to write any php expression.

You can use this directive like:

```
@set($var, 10)
@set($var2, 'some string')
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use the package I have published: https://github.com/sineld/bladeset

Then you easily set your variable:

```
@set('myVariable', $existing_variable)

// or

@set("myVariable", "Hello, World!")
```

Answer (score 4):

As for my elegant way is like the following

```
{{ ''; $old_section = "whatever"; }}
```

And just echo your `$old_section` variable.

```
{{ $old_section }}
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you have** PHP 7.0:

**The simple and most effective way is with assignment *inside brackets***.

The rule is simple: Do you use your variable more than once? Then declare it the first time it's used within brackets, keep calm and carry on.

```
@if(($users = User::all())->count())
  @foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
  @endforeach
@else
  There are no users.
@endif
```

And yes, I know about `@forelse`, this is just a demo.

Since your variables are now declared as and when they are used, there is no need for any blade workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Assign variable to the blade template, Here are the solutions

We can use `<?php ?>` tag in blade page

```
<?php $var = 'test'; ?>
{{ $var }
```

OR

We can use the blade comment with special syntax

```
{{--*/ $var = 'test' /*--}}
{{ $var }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this same issue. But I was able to manage this problem by using following code segment. Use this in your blade template.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$old_section = "whatever" }}">

{{$old_section }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can - but then again, this kind of logic should probably be handled in your controller and passed into the view already set.

Comment: Some variables are strictly for views. `$previous_group_name`, `$separator_printed`, etc.

Comment: If it is only for views, you should just pass it to the view from the controller. If you want it available to all views, see my answer above using `app/controllers/BaseController.php`.

Comment: I'm using multiple arrays to send all my $data to the view

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to assign a value to a key and use it many times in my view. For this case, you can use `@section{"key", "value"}` in the first place and then call `@yield{"key"}` to output the value in other places in your view or its child.

Answer (score 2):

In laravel8

```
@php

 $name="Abdul mateen";

{{ echo $name; }}
    
@endphp
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacking comments is not a very readable way to do it. Also editors will color it as a comment and someone may miss it when looking through the code.

Try something like this:

```
{{ ''; $hello = 'world' }}
```

It will compile into:

```
<?php echo ''; $hello = 'world'; ?>
```

...and do the assignment and not echo anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to practice to define variable in Controller and then pass to view using `compact()` or `->with()` method.

Otherwise #TLGreg gave best answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good extention for Blade [radic/blade-extensions](https://packagist.org/packages/radic/blade-extensions). After you add it you can use @set(variable_name, variable_value)

```
@set(var, 33)
{{$var}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be better to keep the logic in the controller and pass it to the view to use. This can be done one of two ways using the 'View::make' method. I am currently using Laravel 3 but I am pretty sure that it is the same way in Laravel 4.

```
public function action_hello($userName)
{
    return View::make('hello')->with('name', $userName);
}
```

or

```
public function action_hello($first, $last)
{
    $data = array(
        'forename'  => $first,
        'surname' => $last
    );
    return View::make('hello', $data);
}
```

The 'with' method is chainable. You would then use the above like so:

```
<p>Hello {{$name}}</p>
```

More information here:

http://three.laravel.com/docs/views

http://codehappy.daylerees.com/using-controllers

Comment: Presentation logic is best kept in the view. Sometimes, you need to create a variable from within the view. e.g. to format a date. `$format='Y-m-d H:i:s';` that way you can re-use that format within the view. This certainly does not belong in the controller. That said, in response to the question... There is nothing wrong with `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and found what I think to be the correct solution with [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

View Composers allow you to set variables every time a certain view is called, and they can be specific views, or entire view templates. Anyway, I know it's not a direct answer to the question (and 2 years too late) but it seems like a more graceful solution than setting variables within a view with blade.

```
View::composer(array('AdminViewPath', 'LoginView/subview'), function($view) {
    $view->with(array('bodyClass' => 'admin'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel 5 you can easily do this . see below

```
{{--*/ @$variable_name = 'value'  /*--}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend blade by using the extend method as shown below..

```
Blade::extend(function($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\@var(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
});
```

after that initialize variables as follows.

```
@var $var = "var"
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the blade file, you can use this format

```
@php
  $i++
@endphp
```

Answer (score -2):

works in all versions of blade.

```
{{--*/  $optionsArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','J','K'] /*--}}
```