# Where to place Blade::extend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to add the following code to my laravel project to support the break and continue statements in blade.

This is the code:

```
Blade::extend(function($value)
{
  return preg_replace('/(\s*)@(break|continue)(\s*)/', '$1<?php $2; ?>$3', $value);
});
```

I have no idea however where to place it, any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no requirement telling you where you should put the code, you could even put it in your `routes.php` (which is a bit messy of course). You only have to make sure that it's loaded when laravel processes a page view.

In this case, creating a new file `blade_extensions.php` somewhere and including it in `start/global.php` might be a good solution.

PS: Be sure to clear out your compiled views, as Blade only recompiles the views if it detects a change, so if you've just plonked in this code it won't work until you clear out the views.

Comment: issue with this when using composer's autoload: `Class 'Blade' not found`. :(

Answer (score 34):

### Laravel 5 alternative

1) create `app/Providers/BladeServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /* @datetime($var) */
        \Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
        {
            $pattern = $compiler->createOpenMatcher('datetime');

            return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\')); ?>', $view);
        });

        /* @eval($var++) */
        \Blade::extend(function($view)
        {
            return preg_replace('/\@eval\((.+)\)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $view);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

2) in `config/app.php` add

```
<?php

return [

    // ...

    'providers' => [

        // ...

        'App\Providers\BladeServiceProvider',
```

3) run `php artisan clear-compiled`

4) in your template use `@datetime($updated_at)` or `@eval($var = 1)`, `@eval($var++)` for example

5) important remark

> `blade` templates are cached, try to make a dummy change in blade, this way laravel will recompile the template – sbedulin Feb 9 at 17:43

### In addition to sbedulin's great solution for Laravel 5

a) run `php artisan clear-compiled` might be helpful

b) I changed the code for

`$pattern = $compiler->createOpenMatcher('datetime');`

and

`return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\')); ?>', $view);`

<strike>because the example from the [Laravel 5 Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#extending-blade) will not work.</strike>

<strike>The [example](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#extending-blade) is corrected now.</strike>

The example was removed.

Comment: It's not working at this point, Laravel 5.0.28; anyone confirm?

Comment: Worked for me after the dummy change in the view file (Laravel Framework version 5.0.28)

Comment: Does anyone know if you can do multiple parameters `@formatDate($obj->date, 'd-m-y')`?

Answer (score 8):

Laravel 5 update:

1) You may want to create `Extensions\BladeExtensions.php` folder\file on the same level as `Models, Providers, Services` folders

2) `BladeExtensions.php`

```php
<?php namespace App\Extensions;

class BladeExtensions {

    public static function register()
    {
        \Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
        {
            $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('datetime');

            return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\'); ?>', $view);
        });
    }

}
```

3) `AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
// ...
use App\Extensions\BladeExtensions;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...
    public function register()
    {
        // ...

        BladeExtensions::register();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow such a luck, I was searching for this about 10 mins and you answered to this old question :) thank you

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I did a "composer dump-autoload" but nothing happens.

Comment: `blade` templates are cached, try to make a dummy change in blade, this way laravel will recompile the template

Comment: To remove cached templates you may also clear `storage\framework\views` and `storage\framework\cache` folders