# How to set a variable in blade (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I try like this :

```
...

    @if(is_null($key['p3']))
        {{--*/$p3 = $key['p3']/*--}}
    @else
        {{ 0 }}
    @endif
    @if(is_null($key['wabku']))
        {{--*/$wabku = $key['wabku']/*--}}
    @else
        {{ 0 }}
    @endif
    <td class="tg-rv4w" width="5%">
        {{ number_format($p3 - $wabku,0,',','.') }}
    </td>

...
```

But, It's not working.

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/laravels-blade-how-can-i-set-variables-in-a-template

Comment: @Raghavendra N, I try like that. But it's not working

Comment: 1) Don't do this. Setup your variables in your controller, or a view composer. 2) If you absolutely must, just open a <?php tag and keep it as short/clean/simple as possible. Actually, scratch that. Just follow #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using laravel-4 template comment syntax to define/set variables which is may be not working with L5.x.

But you can try `@php ($p3 = $key['p3'])`

OR

```
@php
$p3 = $key['p3']
@endphp
```

Above both are same.

**Further you go with create own service provider like**
1 create `BladeServiceProvider`:

```
<?php 
//app/Providers/BladeServiceProvider.php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /* @datetime($var) */
        \Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
        {
            $pattern = $compiler->createOpenMatcher('datetime');

            return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\')); ?>', $view);
        });

        /* @eval($var++) */
        \Blade::extend(function($view)
        {
            return preg_replace('/\@eval\((.+)\)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $view);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

2 Register `BladeServiceProvider`:

```
<?php
//in config/app.php add
return [

    // ...

    'providers' => [

        // ...

        'App\Providers\BladeServiceProvider',
```

Clear complied `artisan clear-compiled`
Assign value to variable `@datetime($updated_at)`

OR

```
@eval($var = 1)
```

Taken reference from: [Laravel 5 alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329541/where-to-place-bladeextend/28641054#28641054)