# LARAVEL define variable into blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in design template i want to define variables to use into html tabs. for example i have two div, parent `div` is `relative` and child is `absolute`. i want to have child smaller than parent.

sample:

```
{{ WIDTH = 326}}
<div class="win7style" style="margin: 0px auto; {{ WIDTH }}px;">
      <div class="win7style" style="{{ WIDTH - 50 }}px;">
```

can i define like with that custom variables?

Comment: did you try???? what happened when you tried???? what worked? what didn't work? what error you got?

Comment: @itachi this is only quastion and can i define custom variables into BLADE?

Comment: hopely useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/laravels-blade-how-can-i-set-variables-in-a-template

Answer (score 1):

{{...}} is used in laravel-blade for output php variable. You should not define variable in view. Instead define that in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Blade template files are nothing else but usual php files. If you really need to define variables inside the template file, you are free to use plain php code.

```
<? $width = 326; ?>
<div class="win7style" style="margin: 0px auto; {{ $width }}px;">
      <div class="win7style" style="{{ $width - 50 }}px;">
```

Comment: Yes this is it. or you can inject the value when returning the view in your route.
the double bracket only echo the data {{ $width }} becomes <?php echo $width ?>