# blade yield in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible to yield variable in jquery?
I want to set a variable in partial views, based on the variable I set a certain menu item as active. 
 I have a menu where I want to yield the active item like this (in my main layout view):

```
function setMenu(){
    $('#menu-item-'@yield('menu-item', 'home')).addClass('active');
}
```

unfortunately this isn't valid. Is it possible to yield with blade in jquery?

my current 'fix'

**View**

```
@if ($menuItem = 'news') @endif
```

**Layout**

```
setMenu('@if(isset($menuItem)){{ $menuItem }}@endif ');
```

Comment: this will help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/laravels-blade-how-can-i-set-variables-in-a-template

Comment: Why is 'home' hard-coded in your example code? Is this jQuery function only on your home page? If so, you could use '#menu-item-home', so obviously not.  The short answer is 'no', you can't use @yield in jQuery obviously. But that's the wrong question -- tell us what you're trying to do, and we can help you do it the correct way. "yield the active item" isn't a thing in jQuery, so can you describe your problem differently?

Comment: @Ben if you use yield you can set a default value, in this case home so if i dont set menu-item the value will be home.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about the default value, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Ben  I want to set a variable in partial views, based on the variable I set a certain menu item as active. I have a menu where I want to yield the active item

Comment: It seems it's invalid because of jquery wrong syntax... $('#menu-item-'@yield('menu-item', 'home')) will output $('#menu-item-''home')...
use @yield inside quantitation => $('#menu-item-@yield("menu-item", "home")') or use + => $('#menu-item-'+@yield('menu-item', 'home'))

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `@yield`, you seem to know the active menu item at render time in PHP.

So I suggest outputting an 'active' class on the active menu item as you output your menu. Something like:

```
<?php $activeMenuItem = View::yieldContent('menu-item', 'home'); ?>
@foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem)
    <?php $isActive = $menuItem->route === $activeMenuItem ?>
    <li class="{{ $isActive ? 'active' : '' }}">
        {!! link_to_route($menuItem->route, $menuItem->name) !!}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The menu is static to save loading time. so i cant run a foreach loop