# Modify a laravel blade variable without displaying it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade code, I need a counter, to give divs that are rendered by a foreach loop unique id's. For that purpose I created a variable in my blade template like this:

```
{{ $counter = 0 }}
```

I use it in the html by just outputting it with `{{ $counter = 0 }}`

and the later on, I increment it like this:  `{{ $counter++ }}`

It all works like a charm, except that at `{{ $counter++ }}` it's not only incrementing the variable, it's also outputting it to the view.

is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 `@if($loop->first)
    Do something on the first iteration.
@endif

@if($loop->last)
    Do something on the last iteration.
@endif`

Comment: that's a cool feature, but I actually need a number for each item in the array, not only the fist and last. I couldn't find a lot of documentation about the loop variable, any idea if it contains more than first and last?

Comment: Bad but a working version `<?php $counter++;?>`

Comment: you can extend Blade. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13019365/844726

Comment: Blade doesn't have a method for defining/modifying a PHP variable; you either need to extend Blade's functionality to handle that, or simply use a `<?php ... ?>` block.

Comment: @ErikL Why don't use: `foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
 # code...
}` where $key is the position number ? ;)

Answer (score 8):

At first adding logic on blade templating is a bad practice, but sometimes we are forced to do, in that case you can just use PHP tags for it like this:

`<?php $counter++; ?>`

Another way to do it on Laravel 5.4 as [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures) indicate:

> In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You
>   can use the Blade @php directive to execute a block of plain PHP
>   within your template:

```
@php
   $counter++;
@endphp
```

If you have your positions on the array keys you can use it on the `@foreach` like this:

```
@foreach ($variable as $key => $value) 
    //current position = $key
    # code...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension do set variables on blade:
https://github.com/RobinRadic/blade-extensions

You can use simple as @set($count, 1) or any value you want.