# assign a value to a variable in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to assign a value to a variable in a laravel blade file based on condition.

```
<?php $status=''; ?>
      @if($user_role=='2'){
        <?php $status='1'; ?>
      }
      @elseif($user_role=='3'){
        <?php $status='2'; ?>
      }
      @elseif($user_role=='4'){
        <?php $status='3'; ?>
      }
```

but {{status}} returns nothing.How to assign a value to a variable in laravel 5.3 blade file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel's Blade: how can I set variables in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/laravels-blade-how-can-i-set-variables-in-a-template)

Comment: It would be better to do this logic in the controller and not in the blade (view)

Comment: @ThomasMoors May be OP wants to show some text according to conditions!!

Comment: @HirenGohel It still would still be better SOC to do the logic in the controller first and pass the data to the view

Comment: Maybe `$user_role` is not 2, 3 or 4

Comment: @linktoahref Possible, let's wait for OP's reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@if($user_role=='2')
  @php $status='1'; @endphp
@endif

@if($user_role=='3')
  @php $status='2'; @endphp
@endif

@if($user_role=='4')
  @php $status='3'; @endphp
@endif
```

> you can check the value by adding echo

```
 @if($user_role=='4')
  @php echo $status='3'; @endphp
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch Statement would be better

```
@switch($user_role)
    @case(1)
        @php $status = 1;@endphp
        or <h1>Status is 1</h1>
        @break

    @case(2)
        Second case...
        @break

    @default
        Default case...
        @php $status = 5;@endphp
@endswitch
```

But most if not all of your logic should be done in a controller

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#switch-statements

if you don't have @switch available in your version of laravel you can always do

```
@php
 switch($user_role) {
  case 1:
      $status = 1;
      break;
  case 2:
      $status = 2;
      break;
 default:
     $status = 5;
}
@endphp
```