# Undefined offset: 0 in blade Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch data from blade template. I am trying but it does not show me anything. In database table there is a value **10** against **u_id**. when my code is like

```
@foreach($school_data as $val)
  <?php 
      $datas2 = \App\criteria::where('u_id', $val->u_id)->get();
      $trck2= $datas2['0']->updated_by_email;
   ?>
@endforeach
```

it shows **Undefined offset: 0**  . But when it is a static value

```
@foreach($school_data as $val)       
 <?php 
      $datas2 = \App\criteria::where('u_id', '10')->get();
      $trck2= $datas2['0']->updated_by_email;
   ?>
@endforeach
```

then it works properly. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to print the values of $val->u_id into the @foreach to debug your code.

Then the proper way to assign a value to a php variable in blade is using the **@php** directive.
[How to Set Variables in a Laravel Blade Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/how-to-set-variables-in-a-laravel-blade-template)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#php

```
@foreach($school_data as $val)
    {{$val->u_id}}
    @php ($datas2 = \App\criteria::where('u_id', $val->u_id)->get()) @endphp
    @php (dump($datas2) ) @endphp
    @php ($trck2 = $datas2['0']->updated_by_email) @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. how can I solve this issue? still it shows that error .

Comment: Can you paste here the controller that is calling this view ?

Comment: It’s much easier to debug datas in the controller rather than in the view

Comment: Or you can try adding this code:
$trck2 = (isset ($datas2['0'])) ? "$datas2['0']->updated_by_email" : "";

Comment: In **$school_data** u_ids are 9 & 10. But in criteria there is only  10 exists. That's why when it check for 9 it shows error. But how can I fix it?

Comment: The Undefined offset: 0 come from this line of code.
**$trck2 = $datas2['0']->updated_by_email**.  
In my previous comment I've suggested you this to substitute it with 
**$trck2 = (isset ($datas2['0'])) ? "$datas2['0']->updated_by_email" : "";**
to avoid the undefined index problem, so when u_ids is 9 and no record are returned in $datas2 you don't try to access to $datas2['0'] that in that case doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks , in this time it doesn't show any error but not showing any value. i have value on db. **{{ (isset ($datas2[0])) ? '$datas2[0]->id' : '' }}**

Comment: @ Davide Casiraghi

Comment: I've edited my code. Try adding a dump in between to check the value of $datas2.

Comment: Ok, so you are not getting any value from the previous query.
What if you temporary change the query to:  $datas2 = \App\criteria::get() 
Do you get any value from the dump in this case?

Comment: Sorry for late. It shows **#items: array:1** values of 1 row. I have an row on that table.

Comment: ok, so in this case when the array has 1 value you get something in the $trck2 variable or is still undefined?

Comment: no no it's not undefined. in this case it shows all fiends. but when i set where condition it does not show any value.

Comment: So if with the where you get no value the problem is in the where.
The possibilities I guess are two: 1)In criteria the column is not called u_id 2) there is no value 10 in the column u_id

Comment: In **criteria** there is a field named u_id (values exist: 10) and in **users** there is a field named id (values exist: 9,10) . I am checking this id with that u_id

Comment: Oh... that was mistake. Thank you so much for giving me your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Array index have is an integer, use :

```
$trck2= $datas2[0]->updated_by_email;
```

Comment: Try this if you want to get single row :
` $datas2 = \App\criteria::where('u_id', $val->u_id)->first(); var_dump($datas2);`