# how to assign variable into if statment in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laraadmin

```
        @foreach ($modules as $module)

                @if ($module->name === "h_car_positions")   $module_name == "history_car_positions";    @endif


            <tr>
                <td>{{ $module->id }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/modules/'.$module->id) }}">{{ $module->name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $module->name_db }}</td>

                <td>{{ Module::itemCount( $module_name ) }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/modules/'.$module->id)}}#fields" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/modules/'.$module->id)}}#access" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></a>
                    <a href="{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/modules/'.$module->id)}}#sort" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></a>
                    <a module_name="{{ $module->name }}" module_id="{{ $module->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete_module" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

i want to assign history_car_positions to $module name when the if statment is true how to do that in blade

Comment: '`=`' instead of '`==`', maybe?

Comment: no i've tried that

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/how-to-set-variables-in-a-laravel-blade-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Variables in a Laravel Blade Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/how-to-set-variables-in-a-laravel-blade-template)

Answer (score 1):

I should first note that your syntax is incorrect - you're comparing (`==`), not assigning (`=`).

But Blade, being an interpreter, has [its own control structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#php) for raw PHP.

However, if you're simply passing this variable into `itemCount`, you may want to evaluate and assign this in your view, rather than directly in the template. It'll be much cleaner for you to maintain.

Comment: i'm very new to blade .i'm editing in the view  and thats the for each for displaying the data i just want to change the value of the name when it's == the condition in the if statment

Comment: the proplem is how to pass the php variable to {{ Module::itemCount( $module_name ) }}

Comment: If `itemCount` doesn't properly read your `$module_name` variable, then this is the other reason why assigning that variable in your view would be helpful.

As for access to your class, you'll need to either call it from its FQCN (`App\Module`, etc) or create an alias. See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-call-a-static-method-inside-a-blade-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `php` directive [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php)

```
@if ($module->name === "h_car_positions")
   @php
      $module_name = "history_car_positions"; // use = instead of ==
   @endphp
@endif
```

Comment: when i try : {{ Module::itemCount(@php $module_name  @endphp) }} i get syntax error, unexpected '<'    and when i try that   : <td>{{ Module::itemCount( $module_name ) }}</td> i get undefined variable $module_name

Comment: You got 'undefined variable ...' message because `$module_name` is only defined when `$module->name === "h_car_positions"`. Just define it beforehand or add an else statement.

Comment: even when i made the else statment i got same error the proplem is how to pass the php variable to {{ Module::itemCount( $module_name ) }}

Answer (score 0):

Use php tags

```
@if ($module->name === "h_car_positions")  <?php $module_name = "history_car_positions"; ?> @endif
```

Comment: the proplem is how to pass the php variable to {{ Module::itemCount( $module_name ) }}

Comment: The problem is really your inconsistent naming strategy, it would be far better to redefine `$module->name` to use ""history_car_positions" in the first place.

Comment: i have also tried so :      @if ($module->name === "h_car_positions")  <?php $module->name = "history_car_positions" ?>