# how can we define a loop variable for foreach loop in laravel php blade tempalte

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried this but it got printed in fronted

```html
{{ $x=1}}
@if(count($bookings))
    @foreach ($bookings as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $x !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->service->id !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->service->title !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->full_name !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->email !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->phone !!}</td>
            <td>{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->booking_date))  !!} {!! $data->slot_start_from !!}</td>
        {{$x++}}
    @endforeach
```

This code not working value of x got printed . i don't want to use code php code here any good suggestion welcome

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable take a look at that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/how-to-set-variables-in-a-laravel-blade-template  see this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for loop variable, which exists in Laravel Blade.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

So, just use:

```php
<td>{!! $loop->index !!}</td>
```

If you have Laravel 5.2 and lower, there is no loop variables.
In that case you can use `@php` shortcut

```php
@php $x=1 @endphp
...
<td>{!! $x++ !!}</td>
```

Comment: then set please one of answers as correct, to close question

Answer (score 3):

As @RomanBobrik said, use the loop variable `$loop` to get the iteration

```php
    @foreach ($bookings as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->service->id }}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->service->title !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->full_name !!}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
            <td>{!! $data->phone !!}</td>
            <td>{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->booking_date))  !!} {!! $data->slot_start_from !!}</td>

    @endforeach
```

Comment: do we need to define $loop variable or it is predefined?

Comment: @AkshayKumar it's a loop variable present when you use a blade loop. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: @AkshayKumar can u help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990038/laravel-filter-reset-after-next-page-click-in-paginate

Comment: yeah sure i will try