# How to hide button in vuejs and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to hide the button if there is no data in the table I have no Idea how to do it because I am new in vuejs. any help would be highly appreciated.
if there is any other way to do it please let me know.

**HTML Code in Employee.vue is :**

```html
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom:-29px;">
   <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="delt" v-show="hidebutton">
     <i class="fas fa-user-minus"></i>
     Delete Multiple

  </button>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="16" align="center">
             <p v-if="employees.data!=undefined && employees.data.length == 0 || employees.data!=undefined && employees.data.length=='' "
                              class="text-center alert alert-danger">There is no data in the Table 
<!--how to call the hidebutton() function inside the p tag-->

             </p>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript function in Employee.vue is :**

```html
<script>
       hidebutton() {
        document.getElementById("btndel").style.visibility = "hidden";
        },
</script>
```

Comment: `v-show="hidebutton"` ... one would usually have a `data` or `prop` value that is Boolean ... one does not call a function that manipulates the DOM

Comment: simply add `:show="employees.data.length"`

Comment: @Bravo Don't worry, I have fix the indentation.

Comment: Not in the question you want us to read and help you with :p

Comment: yeah Bravo you are right I will try next time I was a little bit in harry sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the hidebutton function like below the function returns a boolean value so you vue can handle the show/hide state with v-show property.

```
hidebutton() {
    return employees.data!==undefined || employees.data !== '' || employees.data !== null;
}
```

Comment: or use a calculated value instead saves you `()` on the `v-show="hidebutton"` :p

Comment: You can use same method for v-if which is in p tag

Comment: Can someone help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990038/laravel-filter-reset-after-next-page-click-in-paginate

Answer (score 1):

The v-show value "hidebutton" must be also declared in the data-property of your Vue instance.
If it has the value "false" the button will be hidden and viceversa.
You can set "hidebutton" dynamically.

Comment: it can be a function that returns a Boolean :p