# How to get old input array in blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have some code like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tag">Tag</label><br>
    <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" 
           class="form-control form-control-lg @error('tag') is-invalid @enderror" 
           id="tag" name="tag[]" value="{{old('tag')}}" placeholder="Enter tag">
    @error('tag') <div class="text-danger"> {{ $message }} </div> @enderror
</div>
```

how to get old value array in laravel blade, in this case i want to get old value of tag?

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs with name=tag[] ?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/input-old-and-array

Comment: i have multiple value

Comment: Roman pointed you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: However, I think what you mean is you have one input field, and you use that to have many tags, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use dot notation with index

as suggested here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/input-old-and-array

```php
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" 
           class="form-control form-control-lg @error('tag') is-invalid @enderror" 
           id="tag" name="tag[]" value="{{old('tag.0')}}" placeholder="Enter tag">
...
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" 
           class="form-control form-control-lg @error('tag') is-invalid @enderror" 
           id="tag" name="tag[]" value="{{old('tag.1')}}" placeholder="Enter tag">
```

Comment: @roman can u help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990038/laravel-filter-reset-after-next-page-click-in-paginate

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution for this is to do it with javascript if you have one input so you need to store the array in javascript variable then just add the value to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="groups[]" class="multi-default" id="groups" placeholder="Groups" multiple>
    <option value="" placeholder>Groups</option>
        @foreach ($groups as $group)
            <option value="{{ $group->id }}" title="{{ $group->id }}"
                {{is_array(old('groups',$groups??[]))&&in_array($group->id,old('groups',$group_data??[]))?'selected':null}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely work

```
@if (!is_null(old('product_highlights')))
    @foreach (old('product_highlights') as $highlight)
        {{$highlight}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```