# Grouping related models by pivot

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to group related model by pivot data, but this returns only one record of the related for each group. How can I group quiz records by column parent, which is saved in pivot table?

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)
    ->with(['quiz' => function($query) use ($md) {
        $query->where('md_id',$md)->groupBy('pivot_parent');
    }])
    ->first();
```

Comment: first() will return you single record, instead of first() use get()

Comment: can some one help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990038/laravel-filter-reset-after-next-page-click-in-paginate

Comment: I tried and it returns the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what did you got

```
 $user= User::where('id', $id)->whereHas('quiz', function($query) 
     use($md){
            $query->where('md_id', '=', $md)- 
   >groupBy('pivot_parent');
        })->first();
```

Comment: this will not work since you are not defining the related model in whereHas. Even if you define it, it returns only the user without quiz, because there is no 'with' query

Comment: Theres no need to use with becaus3 in whereHas we use that function

Comment: @TanvirAhmed can u help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990038/laravel-filter-reset-after-next-page-click-in-paginate