# Generate random number within @if-directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using `laravel 6` and I am currently using the following:

```
@if($randomNumb<0.5)
 // do sth
@endif
```

My problem with the above code snippet is that I pre-calculate the random number in the backend and then hand it to the blade template. Therefore, I get all the time the same random number, if I am using the above code-snippet more than one time in my blade-template.

Any suggestions how to calculate a *unique* random number directly in the `@if`-directive.

Appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with just calculating it right on the blade page each time you need it, especially if you need a unique value that would not have been passed from the controller.

```
@if(mt_rand(1, 100)  < 50)
    // do something
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
@php
    $randomNum = rand(0, 99) / 10;
@endphp
@if($randomNum < 0.5)
 // do sth
@endif
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002626/how-to-set-variables-in-a-laravel-blade-template)

I think it was helpful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use this multiple times,

```
@php

echo(rand(0,0.5));

@endphp
```