# Declaring a variable in blade php (LARAVEL UPDATED)

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, variables, laravel-blade

I have a simple project where Im using laravel with blade.
I recive an array called 'tablero' and I have to see all it values.
I have this code:

[image]

But I received this error:
**Undefined constant "i" (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/tablero2.blade.php)**
How do i define i?

Comment: If you want to go more professionally way you should check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618878/15167087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops)

> In addition to conditional statements, Blade provides simple
> directives for working with PHP's loop structures. Again, each of
> these directives functions identically to their PHP counterparts:

##### Solution one:

```php
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($tablero); $i++)
    <p> {{ $tablero[$i] }} </p>
@endfor
```

##### Solution two:

```php
@foreach ($tablero as $tab)
    <p> {{ $tab }} </p>
@endforeach
```

##### Solution three:

```php
@php($i = 0)

@while ($i < count($tablero))
    <p> {{ $tablero[$i] }} </p>
    @php($i++)
@endwhile
```

Answer (score 0):

add this before foreach

```
@php 
 $i = 0;
 @endphp
```

Comment: I did it but nothing have changed

Comment: change i to $i  .